# Best way generate small solid circle on a blank screen in a specific position?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

--> a number of circles will be drawn over a period of time but only one will be shown on screen at a time.
--> user will click on the circle when the program registers the click, it will show the next circle.
--> the position of each circle is known, only they will appear randomly at different execution.

I have considered a linear layout filled with a lot of imageview(30 of them), every imageview has the same source, a small red dot, generated and stored in the res/drawable folder. code for the dot is:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Large red circle -->
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="0dp"
                android:color="#000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size
                android:width="30dp"
                android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

I am thinking about using `isVisible()` on these imageviews to hide and show them at different times. this doesn't seem very efficient to me. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve that is to create a single custom `View` with `onDraw` overridden.

Then, inside `onDraw` you can simply draw as many circles as you want on the `Canvas` object. There are thousands of threads here on StackOverflow describing how to do that. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954596/how-to-draw-circle-by-canvas-in-android).

Remember that you will have to call `setWillNotDraw(false)` on your `View` to cause your custom `onDraw` to be executed.

When the user clicks on the circle, simply record that even and call `invalidate()`. `onDraw` will be called once again and you can draw proper number of circles for the updated state.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will try it out :) could you please tell me what kind of performance improvement i am getting from using "Canvas" object instead of lots of imageview?

Comment: A major one. You're utilising a single relatively light custom view instead of using a ton of `ImageViews`. Which will be much lighter for the device. Additionally you have a single place where you can easily calculate coordinates of circles. Inserting new `Views` in some layout and making sure they are added correctly will be a pain in the ass.

Comment: I am using canvas.drawCircle to get the circles. but how do i know my circle is clicked ? this "canvas.drawCircle" returns a void so i actually don't have any object to add a listening method. any idea how can i register the user clicks?

Comment: Add an `OnTouchListener` that is using a `GestureDetector` to detect clicks. Based on the coordinates of the `MotionEvent` with action `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` you can determine if the click was within a particular circle bounds.

Comment: is there any special function for finding "action MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN you can determine if the click was within a particular circle bounds." ?  or do i just do a comparison in a IF statement? like if point.x > 250 & point.x<150 ?

Comment: You will have to start trying to figure out stuff by yourself, I'm not here to write the code for you. Check `MotionEvent` methods. There are methods `getAction()`, `getX()` and `getY()`. Those three should get you going.