# How to make a xy circle graph in android

Tags: android, graph, opengl-es, android-canvas

I'm trying to develop a app with a teacher of mine to help students with some math subjects. The problem is that I'm stuck on how to make a proper beautiful XY graph with circles (such as x²+y²=R²). I'm pretty much a noobie in programming, but I'm just asking for some directions on how to do it.

I've tried chart libs such as Androidplot, MPAndroidchart etc, but as far as I could differ, they aren't made to deal with circles because of axis proportion issues (I ended up with elipses).

I already know some openGL (but not much) and I've heard about drawing with the Canvas. Which direction should I take? Or do anyone knows a graph lib that could solve my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw circle by canvas in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954596/how-to-draw-circle-by-canvas-in-android)

Comment: "duplicate" in the sense that it contains all the necessary info to enable you to draw a circle. The rest is just plain old maths