# how to make a custom circular shape with other shapes at run time?

Tags: java, android, vector

i get this photo from my UI designer he give me vector in full size with all circle around it, like this:

[image]

i import the full vector in android studio and set name for all paths in there, and select them in run time, so i can make them visible or invisible and change color
i think if i have a vector with max circle and select vector paths , maybe work

but my problem is have to make it in run time , because the number of circle defined by user , between 25 to 30

dose anybody have any idea ,how to make this?

Comment: I like that design. But what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle is 360 degrees, so if you want e.g. 30 points on that circle, you need a point every 360 / 30 = 12 degrees.

So now you dust off the cobwebs of your math skills and use the sine and cosine functions (see class `Math`) to calculate where those points are.

Then draw small circles centered on those points.

Comment: i dont know how draw circles on perimeter of the circle and how set degrees

Comment: Wait, programming requires math skills? _backs away slowly_

Comment: @mohamadrezaei How to "set" degrees: `for (double degree = 0; degree < 360; degree += 360d / NumberOfCircles) { ... }` --- How to draw circle: See "[How to draw circle by canvas in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17954596/5221149)" --- How to calculate position of circles: See my answer ("math skills"). Do a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sine+and+cosine).