# How to set a views shape and background color programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, background, shapes

I have to create a circle shape and paint it randomly but I have to do it programmatically.
It has to be look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY0JZ.png)

**TextView that needs background**

```
val tvAuthorSubtext = TextView(context)
tvAuthorSubtext.apply {
   text = "AA"
   textSize = 10f
   setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
   gravity = Gravity.CENTER
   typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.ubuntu)
   layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(72, 72)
   setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_author_shape)
   }
```

**R.drawable.bg_author_shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <corners android:radius="12dp" />
   <solid android:color="@color/black" />
</shape>
```

**getBackgroundRandomColor Function**

```
fun getRandomBackgroundColor() :Int {
  val colorArray : MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
  colorArray.add(R.color.aqua)
  colorArray.add(R.color.bright_blue)
  colorArray.add(R.color.bright_purple)
  colorArray.add(R.color.bright_pink)
  colorArray.add(R.color.bright_green)
  colorArray.add(R.color.orangey_yellow)
  colorArray.add(R.color.tealish)

  val rnds = (0..(colorArray.size-1)).random()

  return colorArray[rnds]

}
```

1. Is there any way to run functions in drawable xmls?
2. Is there any way to change shape drawable background color without changing its shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the background color of your drawable shape in xml.
For dynamically changing the color of your shape you have to create custom views.

I came up with these two approaches :

Approach Number 1 :
Creating Custom View using Canvas And Paint.
Here is an useful example of how to create Circle shape programmatically and assign color to it.

[Creating CustomView using Canvas And Paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954596/how-to-draw-circle-by-canvas-in-android/31180653)

you can also draw Text when drawing your shape on `onDraw()` method.

Approach Number 2 :
Creating Custom View by extending The `View` or other `ViewGroup` Classes.
Here is a simple sample of the way you should doing it.

```
public class ColorOptionsView extends View {

private View mValue;
private ImageView mImage;

public ColorOptionsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.Options, 0, 0);
    String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.Options_titleText);
    int valueColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.Options_valueColor,
            android.R.color.holo_blue_light);
    a.recycle();

    // more stuff
}
```

}